# Is it possible to use gRPC service as a apache beam source and sink?

Tags: grpc, apache-beam, grpc-java, apache-beam-io

I want to source and sink the data using gRPC service instead of any persistent storage. These services will fetch and persist the data from a cloud database. Is it possible to use only gRPC services as a beam data source and sink?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just write a composite transform that uses your service to write data. Details see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/#sinks.